# Laravel Email Verification for Vue SPA

Tags: laravel, email, vue.js, single-page-application, email-verification

How can I implement Laravel's Email Verification on a Vue SPA with Vue Router?

So far I have tried to handle email verification by altering the VerificationController verify and resend methods. I then created a new notification and added API routes for the Verification.

When the verification link is generated and sent to user's email, the verification url is something like:

https://foobar.test/email/verify/1?expires=1565276056&signature=b15ccd7d6198bdcf81eea4f5cb441efe8eb2d6d5b57a1ce0b1171e685613d917

When the link is clicked, it opens up a page but it does nothing on the backend as the @verify api route is not hit.

Any suggestions?

VerificationController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;


class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */

    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:600,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }

    /**
     * Show the email verification notice.
     *
     */
    public function show()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function verify(Request $request)
    {
      $userID = $request[‘id’];
      $user = User::findOrFail($userID);
      $user->email_verified_at = date("Y-m-d g:i:s");
      $user->save();

      return response()->json('Email verified!');
    }

    /**
     * Resend the email verification notification.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function resend(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return response()->json('The email is already verified.', 422);
        }

        $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

        return response()->json('We have e-mailed your verification link!');
    }


}
```

VerifyEmail.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Carbon\Carbon;


use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail as VerifyEmailBase;


class VerifyEmail extends VerifyEmailBase
{

    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
      return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
      ‘verification.verify’, Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), [‘id’ => $notifiable->getKey()]
      );

    }
}
```

Api.php

```
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

Comment: You might have missed to add `implements MustVerifyEmail` to that one. If this interface implementation is missing, the mail checking methods won't do anything. Could you post or check your User model?

Comment: Why do you think it isn't hit? It matches exactly. Do you have prefix on your API path?

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue with my angular SPA. Not sure you still need help but hope my answer will help somebody.

So while laravel `UrlGenerator::signedRoute` isn't flexible enough (You can subscribe to this [idea](https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1617). Not the same case, but related to this) we have to implement url signature on our own.

In your `VerifyEmail` class:

```
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
        // collect and sort url params
        $params = [
            'expires' => Carbon::now()
                ->addMinutes(Config::get('auth.verification.expire', 60))
                ->getTimestamp(),
            'id' => $notifiable->getKey(),
            'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
        ];
        ksort($params);

        // then create API url for verification. my API have `/api` prefix,
        // so i don't want to show that url to users 
        $url = URL::route(
            'api:auth:verify',
            $params,
            true
        );

        // get APP_KEY from config and create signature
        $key = config('app.key');
        $signature = hash_hmac('sha256', $url, $key);

        // generate url for yous SPA page to send it to user
        return url('verify-email') . '?' . http_build_query($params + compact('signature'), false);
    }
```

After that in your SPA you should get url params and invoke API request. I'll specify Angular example but it should be easy to adapt it to Vue.

```
// on component load
ngOnInit() {

  // get query params from current route   
  this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {

    // generate API url. Make sure your query params come in the same order
    // as in signature generation. By default signature check middleware 
    // extracts `signature` param so `expires` is the only param that
    // is checked so order doesn't matter, but if you need another params -
    // it can turn into a problem 
    const url = this.router.createUrlTree(['api', 'auth', 'verify', data.id, data.hash],
      {queryParams: {expires: data.expires, signature: data.signature}}).toString();

    // make API request. if signature check fails - you will receive 403 error
    return this.http.get(url).subscribe();
  });
}
```

Another easier way i see is to generate direct API url and send it to user as you did. And after verifying just redirect browser to your SPA. I just can't understand why it don't work in your case. Maybe you have some rewrite rules in your webserver config so your actual domain name doesn't match with your `APP_URL`? Or maybe you serve your API in another port?

Answer (score 1):

Here what I did  to solve the problem. Go to AuthServiceProvider

```
/**
   * Register any authentication / authorization services.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function boot()
  {
    $this->registerPolicies();

    //

    VerifyEmail::createUrlUsing(function ($notifiable) {
      $params = [
        "expires" => Carbon::now()
          ->addMinutes(60)
          ->getTimestamp(),
        "id" => $notifiable->getKey(),
        "hash" => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification()),
      ];

      ksort($params);

      // then create API url for verification. my API have `/api` prefix,
      // so I don't want to show that url to users
      $url = \URL::route("verification.verify", $params, true);

      // get APP_KEY from config and create signature
      $key = config("app.key");
      $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $url, $key);

      // generate url for yous SPA page to send it to user
      return env("APP_FRONT") .
        "/auth/verify-email/" .
        $params["id"] .
        "/" .
        $params["hash"] .
        "?expires=" .
        $params["expires"] .
        "&signature=" .
        $signature;
    });
  }
}
```

add this to api.php

```
Route::get("/verify-email/{id}/{hash}",
    VerifyEmailController::class)
    ->name("verification.verify");
```

add this to VerifyEmailController.php

```
  public function __construct()
  {
       $this->middleware('auth:sanctum');
       $this->middleware('signed');
       $this->middleware('throttle:6,1');
  }

 /**
   * Mark the authenticated user's email address as verified.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\EmailVerificationRequest  $request
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
   */
  public function __invoke(EmailVerificationRequest $request)
  {
    if ($request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
      return response()->json(
        [
          "message" => "Given email is already verified.",
        ],
        400
      );
    }

    if ($request->user()->markEmailAsVerified()) {
      event(new Verified($request->user()));
    }

    return response()->json(
      [
        "message" => "Verification complete.",
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

**Front end**

```
async verfyEmail() {
      try {
        const params = new URLSearchParams(this.$route.query)
        let res = await this.$axios.get(
          'verify-email/' +
            this.$route.params.id +
            '/' +
            this.$route.params.hash,
          { params }
        )
        this.$router.push({ name: 'platform-dashboard' })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.response)
        this.$router.push({ name: 'platform-dashboard' })
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is pretty straightforward.
Using the `temporarySignedRoute` you need to specify the route, the default is `verification.verify`, expiration time and parameters.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Carbon\Carbon;


use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail as VerifyEmailBase;


class VerifyEmail extends VerifyEmailBase
{

    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return string
     */
    protected function verificationUrl($notifiable)
    {
      return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
          'verification.verify',
           now()->addMinutes(60),
           ['id' => $notifiable->id, 'hash' => sha1($notifiable->getEmailForVerification())]
    );

    }
}
```

Comment: This creates the URL that will be in the e-mail the registered user receives but doesn't explain how to handle that in the VueJS frontend. As I understand from the previous answer, the params from that URL need to be handled in a controller but the specifics are not clear as the example uses Angular.